# Can't add app to fanpage

Tags: facebook, addition, facebook-page

I have setup an App in dev. area. but I can't add it to a Fanpage where I'm admin. Normally there is this "View App Profil Page". This time it isn't. Any idea why it is like that? I'm admin from that page, but haven't made the page. Is that a problem?

Comment: can you show your steps to add app to your page?

Comment: Everybody should also read this -> https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/ . Facebook stopped creating the App Profile Pages automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this link:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOURAPPID&next=YOURDOMAIN
```

The facebook documentation can be found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: You can also use the API directly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Answer (score 2):

you also can try this one ,

```
https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=%20<appidtoadd>&pages
```

Answer (score 1):

or also you can try my "fix" @ http://admine.eu/addapp.html

here is part of the source and actually all you need:

window.open("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id="+document.getElementById("appid").value+"&next="+document.getElementById("appurl").value,"PageTab","width=1000,height=300")

+document.getElementById("appid") is the id of your app
+document.getElementById("appurl") is the canvas or tab URL of your app

Answer (score 1):

I have an easier FREE solution for your problem - Just go here:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Add-App-To-Fan-Page/267581953297317

Enter your app ID and click the button

Answer (score 1):

Install [this](https://gist.github.com/4012117) bookmarklet to install apps on fanpages quickly